# How do I create a method that takes the position of various objects from separate ArrayLists and sets them in numerical order?

Tags: java, arraylist

## The Program

This is a multi-purpose calculator that is designed to read in an equation and return the answer. Currently, the program can execute equations with any number of operations in any order and return the correct answer. This is completed by a method separating each character in the user input into an appropriate category.

Currently, there are three categories for characters of the user input to go into.

### *EquationNumber*

- Object with two fields. Designed to hold a number and track its position.
- The first field, ***number***, holds the actual number stored as a double.
- The second field, ***position***, tracks the position of the number **in the equation**.

> **Important Note**: the position field tracks the position of the object in the equation, not the user input. For example, if the user enters 25+5, the number 25 will occupy position 0, and the plus operator will occupy position 1. This contrasts with the string form where the 2 and 5 that compose the number twenty-five occupy positions 0 and 1.

### *Operator*

- Object with two fields. Designed to hold an operator symbol and track its position.
- The first field, ***operator***, stores the operator symbol as a char.
- The second field, ***position***, tracks the position of the operator symbol **in the equation**.

### *Parenthesis*

- Object with four fields. Designed to hold parenthesis symbols and track its position. Additionally, this object tracks whether its an open or closed parenthesis.
- The first field, ***operator***, stores the parenthesis symbol as a char.
- The second field, ***position***, tracks the position of the operator symbol **in the equation**.
- The third field, ***begin***, is a boolean field that is true if the parenthesis is an open one.
- The fourth field, ***end***, is a boolean field that is true if the parenthesis is an closed one.

## Solving the Equation

The program solves the problem by placing each object into an ArrayList, there are three ArrayLists, one for each object type. The calculation is completed by first searching for the numbers adjacent to multiplication and division symbols. Solving the specific calculations and inserting the new number into the position of the old number while deleting the second number used in the calculation. The used symbol is also removed from its respective ArrayList. The same principles are applied to addition and subtraction. The code for the multiplication and division method is attached below.

```
public static void solveMultiplicationAndDivision(){
        double combine;

        //compare numbers against operators and solve accordingly
        for (int i = 0; i < equationNumbers.size() - 1; i++){
            if (operatorcount < operators.size() && operators.get(operatorcount).symbol == '*'){
                combine = equationNumbers.get(i).number * equationNumbers.get(i + 1).number;
                EquationNumber e = new EquationNumber(equationNumbers.get(i).position, combine);
                equationNumbers.set(i, e);
                equationNumbers.remove(i + 1);
                i = -1;
                operatorcount++;
            }
            else if (operatorcount < operators.size() && operators.get(operatorcount).symbol == '/'){
                combine = equationNumbers.get(i).number / equationNumbers.get(i + 1).number;
                EquationNumber e = new EquationNumber(equationNumbers.get(i).position, combine);
                equationNumbers.set(i, e);
                equationNumbers.remove(i + 1);
                i = -1;
                operatorcount++;
            }
            else
                operatorcount++;
        }

         //clear used operators since multiplication and division runs first
        for (int j = 0; j <= operatorcount && j < operators.size(); j++){
            if (operators.get(j).symbol == '*' || operators.get(j).symbol == '/')
                operators.remove(j);
        }
        operatorcount = 0;
    }
```

This code works in conjunction with its addition/subtraction counterpart to solve equations with any number of operations in any order.

## Context of the Problem

Currently, the code is capable of accurately solving any equation that only uses the four major operators. However, when introducing parenthesis, I have encountered issues when the parenthesis appears anywhere outside of the beginning of the equation or when there are multiple parenthesis within the equation. This is not absolute, as it works sometimes within various combinations but not others, and I have not been able to locate the specific reason why. I have attached the code for the solving parenthesis below.

```
public static void solveParenthesis(){
        Parenthesis open = new Parenthesis(-1, false, false);
        Parenthesis close = new Parenthesis(-1, false, false);
        double combine;
        int counter = 0;

        //loop through Parenthesis arraylist and locate Parenthesis object with highest position and begin = true
        for (int j = 0; j < parenthesisposition.size(); j++){

            //if the subsequent parenthesis is open and of a higher position than the last parenthesis then mark that position for the parser to begin at
            if (parenthesisposition.get(j).begin && parenthesisposition.get(j).position > open.position) {
                open = parenthesisposition.get(j);
            }
            else if (parenthesisposition.get(j).end){
                counter = j;
                close = parenthesisposition.get(j);
                solveMultiplicationAndDivision(open.position, close.position);
            }
        }

    }
```

> **Important Note**: this code is unfinished as it cannot solve addition and subtraction within parenthesis yet. Additionally, this code may need to be modified as the project continues so please take this code block with a grain of salt.

From what I have gathered, the error appears to be related to the positions of each object after solving parenthesis operations. Thus, I am attempting to create a method that realigns all of the positions of all objects when called.

If the method receives this information,

| Object | Position |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 4 |
| * | 7 |
| 5 | 11 |

then the following table should be returned

| Object | Position |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 0 |
| * | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

The problem is that each object type is stored in a different ArrayList, so I am unsure how to complete this task when the positions can potentially be scrambled across the three ArrayLists.

How can I create a method that pulls fields from objects in three separate ArrayLists, sets each field into a specific numerical order as highlighted above, and then returns each object to its original list while maintain the positional order created in this method?

Comment: I think you probably can't solve it this way.  The problem in general is parsing, and it requires a parser.  To store an equation, use a tree, not a list.  You should read up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing

Comment: Perhaps [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).

Comment: @markspace Currently this program can effectively parse through an equation and solve equations that do not involve parenthesis. I am interested in learning why I should use trees over an ArrayList from your perspective.